# I want to change behavior of sub redefine

Tags: perl, function, module

So I am getting the error by design. Sub...redefined.

Say I have a sub Get_Name_SSN...makes a db call etc.
I do not always want to call the db when testing.
So I created Testing.pm that hardcodes some values to be used during testing.
I put `use Testing;` and now I do not need to call the db, *if I comment out my own production subroutines*. 
I would prefer not to go through my code commenting out numerous functions. I doubt it is possible, but could I tell perl to use the function from the imported module library and not the one in the current script?

```
MyScript.pl

use strict;
use warnings;
#only linux
#use diagnostics;

use TestModule;

sub get_name_ssn {
    #call db
}

##################
package TestModule;
use Exporter;

@ISA = qw(Exporter);
@EXPORT = qw(get_name_ssn ...

sub get_name_ssn {
    #return key value pair
}
```

So when I want production, comment out use TestModule. When I wan test, leave TestModule. This does not work, unless I also comment out local sub.

Comment: I'm getting a vague idea what you might be referring to, but perhaps you should give a code example of exactly what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Put the `use TestModule` line **after** the subroutine definition. Currently, the subroutine in `MyScript.pl` is the last one defined, and so that is the subroutine assigned to the name `get_ssn_name`. If you put the subroutine definition first and then imported `TestModule`, the subroutine in `TestModule.pm` would be the last one defined.

Example:

```
# TestModule.pm
sub main::foo { print "test function" };
1;

# script1.pl
use TestModule;
sub foo { print "real function" };
foo();

# script2.pl
sub foo { print "real function" };
use TestModule;
foo();
```

`script1.pl` output:

```
real function
```

`script2.pl` output:

```
test function
```

Comment: All known. I want to force perl to use the imported module, not the one in defined in the script.

Answer (score 0):

The last definition wins, so ensure that the one you want shows up last.

You can load a module at run time with `require`. By that time the one in the script is already defined, even if the `require` line lexically came first. You can change your `use` to:

```
require TestModule;
TestModule->import;
```

However, there's a better solution to this problem. It looks like you want to supply a fake database routine for testing. Instead of the acrobatics, use some form of dependency injection so you can supply the database handle yourself. You can then supply a mock database handle for testing.

Answer (score 0):

Along the same lines as brian_d_foy's advice, it sounds like you need a testing database.  If you have a centralized module to hold your database handle, then it would be very easy for you to trigger your entire codebase to connect to that database instead of your primary.  Then you could do whatever normal procedures that you do and testing your real code.

The following is an example of that type of database module.  I've named it `MyProject::Database`.  if called with `use MyProject::Database qw($dbh);` it will return a live database handle.  However, if called with `use MyProject::Database qw($dbh --testing);` it will connect to a testing database instead, and all normal calls to this `$dbh` will also have to use the testing databse:

```
package MyProject::Database;

### This module is used to create and cache a Database Handle.

use base qw(Exporter);
our @EXPORT = qw($dbh);
our @EXPORT_OK = qw(getConnection)
;
use DBI;

our $DB_NAME = 'MyDB';
our $DB_USER = 'user';
our $DB_PASS = 'pass';
our $DB_HOST = 'localhost';

our $DB_TEST = 'MyTestingDB';

use strict;
use warnings;

# Global Database Handle
#    One unique global database handle is sufficient for most environments.
# For that reason we provide this handle as a shared resource to all packges
# that use this module.
our $dbh;


# Initialize Database Handle
#    This initializes the database handle when this module is used for the
# first time.  For Apache, this should happen each time a child process is
# spawned.
sub import {
    my $module = shift;

    # Filter out options that cause alternative behavior
    my %options;
    @_ = map {/^-/ ? $options{$_}++ && () : $_} @_;
    my $is_testing = delete $options{--testing};
    die "Unknown options passed to " . __PACKAGE__ . ": " join(', ', keys %options)
        if keys %options;

    if ($is_testing) {
        if ($dbh) {
            warn "DBH already created in testing mode.  Will be clobbered.  Be sure to make call to for testing mode before all other use statements";
        }
        $dbh = getConnection($DB_TEST);
    }

    $dbh ||= getConnection();

    MyProject::Database->export_to_level(1, $module, @_);
}


# Child Initialization Handler
#    In some versions of apache/perl, the child initialization is not done
# properly, and the database handle is therefore no initialized.  If this
# occurs, then a ChildInitHandler can be added pointing to here to ensure
# that a connect gets established.
sub handler {
    $dbh = getConnection();
}


# Create a Database Handle
#    This function creates a new Database Handle.  It can be called with alternate
# connect parameters for testing environments etc.
sub getConnection {
    my $name = shift // $DB_NAME;
    my $user = shift // $DB_USER;
    my $pass = shift // $DB_PASS;
    my $host = shift // $DB_HOST;

    # Database URL
    my $url = "dbi:mysql:$name:$host";

    my $handle = DBI->connect($url, $user, $pass) or die "DB connect failed: $DBI::errstr";

    return $handle;
}

1;

__END__
```

Your script is then edited to be the following:

```
#MyScript.pl

use strict;
use warnings;

use MyProject::Database qw($dbh --testing);

#...

my $database = $dbh->do(q{SELECT DATABASE()}) or die $dbh->errstr;
die "Not Testing DB" if $database ne 'MyTestingDB';
```

If you're additionally worried about test script writers not remembering to indicate test mode, then you can enforce that all test scripts end with `.t`.  Then have `MyProject::Database::import` verify that `$0` doesn't end in `.t` unless it's called in testing mode.